# How do I access an alert on a new window when the window hasn't loaded anything yet?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert

I'm running a Selenium script and at one point, we have a new window open and before anything in the window loads, an alert pops up. We switch to the new window and attempt to confirm the alert. This is the same kind of alert we see in other places, but when we try to confirm, or even just try to get the alert object itself, the script hangs, trying to forward `getAlertText` for the next 10 minutes.

[image: getAlertText in debug view]

Finally it fails:

`[1568822219.289][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000`

...which is no surprise. What I don't understand is why we can't get the alert, which looks the same as every other alert I've ever handled through Chrome and Selenium, and why it doesn't return a `NoSuchAlertException` instead of very-slowly failing. I cannot inspect the alert through the developer tools and it doesn't register as a window:

[image: typical Chrome alert]

We're using `driver.switchTo().alert()`. I've also used the `ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()` condition. I've even tried accessing the alert before switching to the new window, which I had no real hopes of working, but when you have nothing logical left you try the illogical stuff.

Has anyone else had this issue? What did you do to overcome it? Thanks!

Comment: Look into `Driver.getWindowHandles();` or `driver.switchTo().alert()`

Comment: does Selenium throw an "unhandled/unexpected alert" type of exception here?

Answer (score 0):

This alert cannot be handled using selenium to handle it you can use sikuli 
 same I have handled using sikuli 
just import sikuli package and write code

```
String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String allow = dir+"/extra/allow.png";
Screen s = new Screen();
Pattern allowimg = new Pattern(allow);
System.out.println("Trying to click on Allow popup...");
Thread.sleep(2000);
s.click(allowimg);
```